# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Im using react-router-dom V 4.0.; react-router v 4.0.0 along with webpack

Index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Nav from './component/nav';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Nav />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

nav.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Match, Miss } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./home"


const Nav = () => {
  return (
      <div>
       <Router>
         <Link to='/home'>Home</Link>
         <Match pattern='/home' component={Home}> </Match>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  };
export default Nav;
```

home.js

```js
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

I tried using both react-router and react-router-dom but I do get the same error. Already tried the solution I found in the internet but the same error occurs. I dont really understand what causes the error.

Edit: Error shown in browser: vendors.js%20line%20203%20%3E%20eval:36:9

Comment: Where exactly is the error, as in where does the error say it is?

Comment: @AndrewLi  it is found on the js file created by webpack. Ill edit my post in paste the the error shown in the browser

Comment: Are you sure you are importing Home conponent in nav.js from the right location. Try console.log(Home) and see if you get the component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri This is what is shown when I run consoloe.log(Home)  => ReferenceError: Home is not defined

Comment: If you get Home undefined when tyring to console.log(Home) in ``const Nav = () => { console.log(Home); ..` Then you should check the location of the home component. Can you attach your directory structure

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Sorry Im a newbie, I run the console.log in the browser. Not in the code itself. WHen I run it in the `..const Nav = () => { console.log(Home); ..`  This is what I get => function Home()

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Im using webpack along with react.

Comment: So - did you figure it out eventually?

Comment: Nope, I downgraded my webpack and used the older syntax and it worked.

Comment: I am getting the same error after upgrading webpack, react, redux, router...